# Loading userform listbox into array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've been using the following *brief* code to load a form's listbox values into an public array.

Dim arrListboxContents as variant

```
arrListboxContents = frmTasks.LboxNames.list
```

(The listbox only contains 5 columns.)

The above works and array contains listbox all values but, oddly, the array's column dimension defaults to 9 even though the listbox has only 5 columns. (The row count is correct, with no extras.)

```
Print Ubound(arrListboxContents,2) = 9
```

I've tried adding **Redim arrListboxContents (x,5)** before loading it from listbox but after I load it and check array is still:

Guess I'll have to return to code that loads array using a loop, which requires more lines of code. (I've done this many times so I know how to do it.)

Just wondering why the array doesn't automatically match the list's column dimension. Anyone have any ideas???

Comment: When asking a question, you will get more help if you provide an reproducible example that someone can actually try out on their own system.

Comment: This question needs a [mcve]

Comment: Check `frmTasks.LboxNames.ColumnCount `

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I thought this was a very simple question, not requiring any more detail.  It appears  Excel's max column count of 10 for listboxes might be setting the array column count at 9 always (0-9 = 10). So, I've gone ahead and written looping code that set's array column count correctly (< 9) to get this done.